# Displaying the values of a multidimensional array in a MessageBox

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, messagebox

I am just now learning about multi-dimensional arrays and message boxes. I am currently have a issue in creating 2 columns in my message box. I can currently get it to print up the random numbers I need, but only in one column. Thanks for the help!

```
string  msg = "";

Random numb = new Random();
int[,] thing = new int[ 10, 2 ];

thing[0, 0] = numb.Next(0,10);
thing[0, 1] = numb.Next(0,10);
thing[1, 0] = numb.Next(0,10);
thing[1, 1] = numb.Next(0,10);
thing[2, 0] = numb.Next(0,10);
thing[2, 1] = numb.Next(0,10);
thing[3, 0] = numb.Next(0,10);
thing[3, 1] = numb.Next(0,10);
thing[4, 0] = numb.Next(0,10);
thing[4, 1] = numb.Next(0,10);

thing[5, 0] = numb.Next(0,10);
thing[5, 1] = numb.Next(0,10);
thing[6, 0] = numb.Next(0,10);
thing[6, 1] = numb.Next(0,10);
thing[7, 0] = numb.Next(0,10);
thing[7, 1] = numb.Next(0,10);
thing[8, 0] = numb.Next(0,10);
thing[8, 1] = numb.Next(0,10);
thing[9, 0] = numb.Next(0,10);
thing[9, 1] = numb.Next(0,10);

foreach (int x in thing) 
msg = msg + x + "\n";
MessageBox.Show(msg, "Table");
```

Comment: `MessageBox.Show(msg, "Table");` is outside the `foreach` loop and thus the printed `msg` is always the one from the last iteration. In C#, you have to use braces for most of multi-line statements, like `foreach`, that is: to see all the values, you would have to write `foreach (int x in thing)
{
    msg = msg + x + "\n";
    MessageBox.Show(msg, "Table");
}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
foreach (int x in thing) 
msg = msg + x + "\n";
MessageBox.Show(msg, "Table");
```

To :

```
for (int i = 0; i < thing.GetLength(0); i++)
    msg += String.Format("{0}   {1}\n", thing[i, 0], thing[i, 1]);
    //msg += thing[i, 0] +  "  " +  thing[i, 1] + "\n";

MessageBox.Show(msg, "Table");
```

Explanation:

Method `GetLength(0)` returns length of dimension for our `x` (it's basically like `array.Length` for simple array but with specific dimension) and we use `i` variable and `for` loop to iterate through it. In `y` we have only 2 elements so we can just use `[0]` and `[1]` indexes as we know there are only two elements there. This explains the line:

```
msg += thing[i, 0] +  "  " +  thing[i, 1] + "\n";
```

Be careful with concatenating string like that, as if you don't add this space `"  "` between your numbers compiler will just add them, so element like `[33, 10]` will be concatenated to string like : `"43 \n"` instead of `"33 10 \n"`.

P.S.
So let's use `String.Format` method to make sure it's formatted well :

`msg += String.Format("{0}   {1}\n", thing[i, 0], thing[i, 1]);`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this question is a duplicate of an existing one, but I cannot find the appropriate precedent. So maybe we are in need of an answer explaining how to format a two-dimensional array for output. This is such an answer. :)

First thing to keep in mind is that the fact that you are displaying this using `MessageBox` is only barely relevant. What you are *really* asking is how to format a two-dimensional array as a string, where that string includes line-breaks between rows in your data, and the columns are lined up in the output. Once you have that string, you can display in any context that uses a fixed-space font (which is actually *not* the `MessageBox`…but it is not hard to create your own `Form` to use as a message box, where you can specify the font used to display the text) and have the output appear as you seem to be asking for.

For example, here's a console program that does what you want:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Random random = new Random();
    int[,] array = new int[10, 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            array[i, j] = random.Next(10);
            if (j > 0)
            {
                sb.Append(", ");
            }
            sb.Append(array[i, j]);
        }
        sb.AppendLine();
    }

    Console.WriteLine(sb);
}
```

Note that I have consolidated the initialization of the array and the formatting of the values into a single piece of code. I have also used nested `for` loops to index each individual element in the array; this allows two things:

1. To initialize the array using loops instead of explicitly writing out each element as you did in your example.
2. To make it easy to recognize the end of a row in the array so that a line-break can be added to the output.

In your example, your random numbers are only ever a single digit. But if you were to want to format numbers that could vary in their number of digits, you would want to pad the output with spaces for the shorter numbers, so that the numbers in the columns of your output lined up. You can do that by adding a width specifier to the output, like this:

```
            sb.AppendFormat("{0,2}", array[i, j]);
```

In the above, rather than using the default formatting as the previous code example does, I am explicitly specifying a format (and calling `AppendFormat()` instead of `Append()` to do so), and in that explicit format, I have included the text `,2`, to indicate that I want the output string to have a minimum width of two characters. The method will add spaces as necessary to ensure that.

I have also changed from simple string concatenation to the use of `StringBuilder`. In your original example, string concatenation is probably not horrible, but it's also not a good habit to get into. When you are repeatedly appending text in a loop, you should always use `StringBuilder`. Otherwise, an excessive number of objects may be created, and as well an excessive amount of time spent copying character data may be spent. Using `StringBuilder` allows the text to be concatenated more efficiently.